# Prolog - Add 1 after an even element in a list

Tags: prolog

I started studying prolog. I want to add an 1 after each even number in a list. Here is my code :

```
member(E,[E|_]).
member(E,[_|T]):-
    member(E,T).
add([],[]).
add([H|T],[H|[1|T1]]):-
    H mod 2=0,!,
    add(T,T1).
add([H|T],[H|T1]):-
    add(T,T1).
```

I tried add([5,6,7],[5,6,1,7]) , add([5,6,7],[5,1,6,7]),etc, but all i got is false,false,false. Please help !

Comment: You actually do not have to implement `member/2`, that is a builtin on almost *all* Prolog systems.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry,sir,but i don't undersant what you mean. I am at beginner--   level ... . This is one of my first programs in prolog. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that:

```
0 mod 2 = 0
```

is `false`. Indeed, since `0 mod 2` is actually short for `mod(0,2)`, and `mod(0,2)` is not equal to `0` in Prolog (except if you *evaluate* `mod(0,2)`). You can evaluate it with the `is/2` predicate. So a quick fix is:

```
add([],[]).
add([H|T],[H|[1|T1]]):-
    0 is H mod 2,
    !,
    add(T,T1).
add([H|T],[H|T1]):-
    add(T,T1).
```

Now it *somehow* works in several directions:

```
?- add([5,6,7],[5,6,1,7]).
true.

?- add([5,6,7],L).
L = [5, 6, 1, 7].

?- add(L,[5,6,1,7]).
L = [5, 6, 7].
```

But still this is not a good idea: you use a cut (`!`). The problem with a cut is usally that the other direction of unifications can be problematic. Furthermore if elements in the list are ungrounded, this means that if you give it `add([1,2,X,4],L).` it will raise an exception. Furthermore imagine that if you do validation, and the second list is a grounded list, but with the pattern `[H|[1|T]]`, the Prolog will jump over that clause, resulting in taking the last clauses, which is *not* the intended behavior. We can rewrite it with a guards on the second clause:

```
add([],[]).
add([H|T],[H|[1|T1]]):-
    0 is H mod 2,
    add(T,T1).
add([H|T],[H|T1]) :-
    \+ 0 is H mod 2,
    add(T,T1).
```

but this is still not very elegant: since it needs `H` to be a grounded number, otherwise it will raise an exception.

We can use the **C**onstraint **L**ogic **P**rogramming library over **F**inite **D**omains for this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

add([],[]).
add([H|T],[H|[1|T1]]):-
    0 #= H mod 2,
    add(T,T1).
add([H|T],[H|T1]):-
    0 #\= H mod 2,
    add(T,T1).
```

Comment: Thank you! It works!
But it is another way,without ! and clpfd to make this program works? I didnt learn yet what this operator is doing...it's something what i found on internet.

Comment: Your cut-version does not work in several directions: `add(L,[6]).` should fail, but in your case it succeeds incorrectly.

Comment: @false: that is exactly what I write below the statement, that cut tends to fail to work multidirectional

Comment: You say "Not it works in several directions:" What do you mean by that? You only give cases where it works.

Comment: With the cut version also add([5,6,7],[5,6,7]) works... it should not.

Comment: Is ! necessary?

Comment: @EduardAdrian: not if you add a guard to the last clause.

Comment: no, it is not required. if you may not use clpfd, take willemvanonsem’s clpfd code, replace #= with =:=, replace #\= with =\= and you’re done.

Comment: @EduardAdrian: I added it to the answer (second solution).

Comment: You are the real MVP. Thank you,again.

Answer (score 3):

You could also opt to use DCGs to describe such lists. Consider the following code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_inserted(L,I) :-
   phrase(inserted(L),I). % the DCG inserted//1 describes I based on L

inserted([]) -->          % if L is empty
   [].                    % I is empty
inserted([X|Xs]) -->      % if the head of the list L
   {X mod 2 #= 0},        % is even
   [X,1],                 % it's in the list I followed by 1
   inserted(Xs).          % the same holds for the tail
inserted([X|Xs]) -->      % if the head of the list L
   {X mod 2 #= 1},        % is odd
   [X],                   % it's in the list I
   inserted(Xs).          % the same holds for the tail
```

If you query this predicate with your example it yields the desired result:

```
?- list_inserted([5,6,7],I).
I = [5, 6, 1, 7] ;
```

The predicate also works in the other direction:

```
?- list_inserted(L,[5,6,1,7]).
L = [5, 6, 7] ;
false.

?- list_inserted(L,[5,1,7]).
L = [5, 1, 7] ;
false.
```

However, the most general query is listing the solutions in an unfair manner: The lists only containing even elements are listed first. Since there are infinitely many of those you'll never get to see a list containing odd elements:

```
?- list_inserted(L,I).
L = I, I = [] ;
L = [_G762],                          % <- [even]
I = [_G762, 1],
_G762 mod 2#=0 ;
L = [_G847, _G850],                   % <- [even,even]
I = [_G847, 1, _G850, 1],
_G847 mod 2#=0,
_G850 mod 2#=0 ;
L = [_G932, _G935, _G938],            % <- [even,even,even]
I = [_G932, 1, _G935, 1, _G938, 1],
_G932 mod 2#=0,
_G935 mod 2#=0,
_G938 mod 2#=0 .
.
.
.
```

You can improve on that by prefixing a goal length/2. This way for every list length all possible combinations of odd and even elements are generated:

```
?- length(L,_), list_inserted(L,I).
L = I, I = [] ;
L = [_G65],                           % <- [even]
I = [_G65, 1],
_G65 mod 2#=0 ;
L = I, I = [_G180],                   % <- [odd]
_G180 mod 2#=1 ;
L = [_G110, _G113],                   % <- [even,even]
I = [_G110, 1, _G113, 1],
_G110 mod 2#=0,
_G113 mod 2#=0 ;
L = [_G228, _G231],                   % <- [even,odd]
I = [_G228, 1, _G231],
_G228 mod 2#=0,
_G231 mod 2#=1 ;
L = [_G265, _G268],                   % <- [odd,even]
I = [_G265, _G268, 1],
_G265 mod 2#=1,
_G268 mod 2#=0 ;
L = I, I = [_G262, _G265],            % <- [odd,odd]
_G262 mod 2#=1,
_G265 mod 2#=1 ;
.
.
.
```